# How do I handle postback in usercontrol from button click on MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, webformsmvp

I have usercontrol inside a webform with a MasterPage.  The MasterPage has a logout button:

```
protected void lbtnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Roles.DeleteCookie();
        Session.Clear();
        Response.Redirect("~/Account/WebLogin.aspx");
    }
```

When I click the logout button, the usercontrol is reloading before the eventhandler above is called, thus making an unnecessary trip to the database.

How should I handle the postback? Is there a way to ignore it in the usercontrol?

Thanks in advance.

Update: I should've mentioned earlier. I'm using an implementation framework "WebFormsMvp". The webform with the MasterPage has several usercontrols which are views that are bound to their respective presenters at runtime.  I'm not handling the Page_Load in any of the user controls as the data is being bound to each user control by the framework before the Page_Load event.

I'll update the tag for this question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to add a completely new aspx / ashx page for signout. That page has its own presenter (or contains a usercontrol which has its own presenter) which contains the signout logic (and redirects back to login page).

Then change your logout link to be a normal [a tag](http://www.yourwebsite.com/logout.aspx) pointing to the new page (rather than using a postback as you are currently).

This approach is basically the same as the second post (the first reply) at http://forums.asp.net/t/1369480.aspx/1, adapted to the way that http://webformsmvp.com/ works.

Comment: This should do it. I'll give it a try later and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Worked great. This was probably the most non-invasive solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't stop(you can override but that's out of scope) a normal `Load` from firing before your `Button` event.  ASP.NET has to reload controls to know something changed in order to be able to fire events. To get a better understanding of how ASP.NET does it's eventing take a look at this article:

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar with Page Life Cycle, but I'll take a look anyway to see if I can pinpoint the problem. I'll update my question to provide more context. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) in `pageload`.

Comment: there is more to this than a simple Page.IsPostBack.  I'll update me question to clarify.

Comment: There's definitely more to it than a simple condition.

Answer (score 0):

huMpty duMpty should still be right in his answer.

You can check for IsPostBack (I think base.IsPostBack) in your presenters as well, before going to the database.

Of course this depends on your presenters, having to always get new data from the DB, then you might need to look at some parameters to skip your DB call..?

Comment: Unfortunately IsPostback is not available in the presenter base. Besides, that would mean that I have to do this check in every presenter (code smell).

Comment: Actually no.. Each presenter should have logic that handles if it should touch the DB or not. This could be several parameters, one being IsPostBack. However I think that you are right on the base presenter not giving access to an IsPostBack property :(